# Getting data from Web API in Angular 2

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, angular

Thanks to tutorial on Angular 2 page called ["Tour of Heroes"](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/), I managed to create a simple Angular 2 application. Then using Enitity Framework I decided to create a database. And fill the list of heroes from it (not from the file). I created Web Api Controller and added simple get method.
Then in `hero.service.ts` I call this method in order to get list of heroes. When I lunch my app it shows the list of heroes but without any values (name and id are blank). When I debug my application in the browser I can see `this.heroes` object in `heroes.component.ts` contains right data. So what is going on? Why aren't `name` and `id` showing?

**hero.service.ts:**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {HEROES} from './mock-heroes';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

    public values: any;

    constructor(public _http: Http) { }

    private _heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:61553/api/values'; // URL to web api

    getHeroes() {
        return this._http.get(this._heroesUrl)
            .map(res => <Hero[]>res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

**heroes.component.ts:**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-heroes',
    templateUrl: 'templates/heroes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['styles/heroes-component.css'],
    directives: [HeroDetailComponent]
})

export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _heroservice: HeroService, private _router: Router) { }

    errorMessage: string;
    public heroes: Hero[];

    selectedHero: Hero;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getHeroes();
    }

    onSelect(hero: Hero)
    {
        this.selectedHero = hero;
    }

    getHeroes() {
        this._heroservice.getHeroes()
            .subscribe(
            value => this.heroes = value,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

    gotoDetail() {
        this._router.navigate(['HeroDetail', { id: this.selectedHero.Id }]);
    }
}
```

**heroes.component.html:**

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
    <li *ngFor="#hero of heroes" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero" (click)="onSelect(hero)">
        <span class="badge">{{hero.Id}}</span> {{hero.Name}}
    </li>
</ul>
<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
    <h2>
        {{selectedHero.Name | uppercase}} is my hero
    </h2>
    <button (click)="gotoDetail()">View Details</button>
</div>
```

**hero.ts:**

```
export class Hero {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
}
```

**Web API Controller:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TestApplicationDataAccess;
using TestApplicationDataAccess.Entities;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TestAppDbContext _dbContext;

        public ValuesController(TestAppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Hero> Get()
        {
            return _dbContext.Heroes;
        }
    }
}
```

**Hero Entity:**

```
namespace TestApplicationDataAccess.Entities
{
    public class Hero
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**JSON retrieved from WEB API Controller:**

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Superman"}]
```

Comment: Do you get proper response in console? Do you convert response into CamelCase or something? in html put `{{heroes|json}}` and tell me what do you get?

Comment: Yes in console it says status: OK. And i can open the json in new tab and see the values like above. When i put `{{heroes|json}}` I don't see nothing...

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not. The console is clear.

Comment: Wait a moment. FYI - this doesn't seem API controller at all as `valueController: controller`, it must be `:ApiController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the issue was related to the visual studio 2015 bug. There was nothing wrong with the code itself. Sometimes changes made in vs were not refreshed in the browser. Updating vs to the latest version helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
getHeroes() {
        this._heroservice.getHeroes()
           .subscribe(res=>{
            this.heroes=res;
            console.log(this.heroes); // make sure you get data here.
         },
         (err)=>console.log(err),
         ()=>console.log("Done")
         );
 }
```

Comment: No, Elvis operator won't help here. The console does not throw any error so the value is not null at least the `hero`.

Comment: `{value => this.heroes = value, console.log(this.heroes)},...` what do you get in console?

Comment: hmm you are not getting data from api. check that first.

Comment: So how come i got the result: `[{"Id":1,"Name":"Superman"}]`, and when i debug i can see in `heroes` object that it contains the array with 1 element with exact same values: 1 and Superman ?

Comment: but you just said, its undefined

Comment: Yes in console it says `undefined`. But in debugger I can see this: [image](http://imgur.com/qdf3zlH)

Comment: how its possible? Can you explain me?

Comment: Check my update. Plus http://plnkr.co/edit/O5vXFcDnb3tZ7FaqAyam?p=preview if you could reproduce here something. I know since you use web api, it is not possible to go with plunker but still if you could come up with something by forking my plunker.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :`public heroes: Hero[] = [];`